# Sending Reminders for Tasks

Tags: scheduled-tasks, rabbitmq, scheduler, amqp, beanstalkd

I have recently been thinking about possible architecture for a simple task reminder system. User will schedule a task and reminder in form of SMS/email/android needs to be sent to all  stakeholders at some x minutes before the task is scheduled to be performed(much in the same way google calendar works). The problem here is to send the reminder at that precise point in time. Here are the two possible approaches I can think of:

**Cron**: I can setup a cron to run every minute. This will scan the table for notifications which need to be sent in the next minute and simply sends the notifications. But, precision is lost as there is always the chance of that +/-1 min error.

**Work Queues**: I can simply put a message with appropriate delay in a queue at the time task was scheduled. Workers will send the notification as and when they receive the message. I can add as many workers as I want in case my real time behavior starts getting affected because of load. There are still a few issues. How to choose the appropriate work queue? I have evaluated `RabbitMq` and `Beanstalk`. While `Rabbitmq` follows standard `AMQP` protocol and is widely suggested, it doesn't provide the `delay` functionality out of the box. There are ways to simulate this using `dead-letter-exchanges` but this will not work in my case because the delay needs to be variable. Beanstalk supports this but the problem is that beanstalk queue resides entirely in memory which I don't like(but can live with). Any possible alternatives?

**Third Approach**: ??????. I am sure a simple desktop notification tool does neither of the two. What technology do they use to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same scenario and we use Redis for long schedules even now reminders for up to 2 years. You can use [Sorted Set](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) where the timestamp is the score.

We use Beanstalkd delay jobs for those kind of reminders where we know it's relatively short term couple of hours, and there is no cancellations, as removing from beanstalkd a delayed message you need to retain the job id in a database for later removal, and that is no viable.

Although you mention memory limit, we use persistence on both Redis/Beanstalkd